# Puppeteer - set navigation timeout for intercepted request

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The script perform navigation to a given HTML string, representing web page. There is the function which works with intercepted requests and `abort` those, which types are not allowed. For all other requests, which request `continue`, I would like to set particular timeout, different from page load timeout (Script doesn't set it, but default `goto` timeout is 30 sec). For example if resource type is `'image'` I would like to wait no more that 5 sec and after abort the request. The following is the script snippet ...

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
let firstDocument = true;
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    const resType = interceptedRequest.resourceType();
    if ((resType === "document" && firstDocument) || settings.getAllowedResourceTypes().indexOf(resType) !== -1) {
        if (resType === "document") {
            firstDocument = false;
        }
        interceptedRequest.continue();
    } else {
        interceptedRequest.abort();
    }
});
await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }).catch((e) => { logger.warn(e, "Unable to load HTML page content."); });
// ... move on with HTML processing
```

Is this possible to set timeout for particular intercepted request only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the puppeteer developers](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2316#issuecomment-410026030) this is currently not supported by the protocol.

But there is a "hacky" way to do it (as described [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2316#issuecomment-379962185)): You can download the resource yourself after intercepting the request and apply a timeout yourself. Keep in mind that you might need to handle cookies and other HTTP headers yourself:

```js
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    const resType = async interceptedRequest.resourceType();
    if (resType === 'image') {
        // download the image yourself
        const body = await Promise.race([
            fetchResourceYourself(interceptedRequest.url()), // might need to take care of cookies, headers, ...
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5 * 1000)) // your timeout
        ]);
        if (body) {
            interceptedRequest.respond({ body });
        } else {
            interceptedRequest.abort();
        }
    } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
});
```

Comment: I end up using overall `timeout` for `goto` function. The time I was trying to save on broken resources, doesn't worth instability of `fetchResourceYourself` function implementation. This become quiet complicated, especially when resource is `document` on it's own (ex.: `iframe` source). Do this via new puppeteer `page` take time on it's own and once again unnecessary complicate solution. The answer is still may help someone else.